# Adding two spaces in front of each sentence

Tags: java

[image: Im failing this test case]

if I have a long String of text, what command or method should i use in order to leave exactly two whitespaces in front of each line?
Suppose

```
String sentences = "The car is blue. 
                    The sky is blue. 
                    The house is blue."
```

The output should be

```
  The car is blue.   
  The sky is blue.   
  The house is blue.


public static String indentByTwoSpaces(String text)
{
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: `String#split` and `StringBuilder` and a `while-loop` are what you are looking for

Comment: Im trying String.replace("\\n", "\\n "), its not working though @ScaryWombat

Comment: Sorry should be replaceAll - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Simple use String.replace

```
System.out.println ("  " + str.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "\r\n  "));
```

Comment: it's not leaving 2 whitespaces in front of the first line

Comment: I'm still not passing a test case, @ScaryWombat. Sorry for asking. I've posted after the original code above

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Split the lines using regex.

**2.** Use the loop for iteration for printing the contents by formatting the
    string provided

NOTE- in case you need to concatenate the string with two spaces in the start then just split and concatenate the string with two spaces <"  "+ --- > and return

```
        String splittedLines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
        int index = 0;
        while(index != splittedLines.length) {
            String.format("  %s", splittedLines[index]);
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: I like this one better than appending the spaces to string itself. Content and presentation should ideally be kept apart. I hope OP takes notice and changes his approach.

Comment: It's not leaving 2 whitespaces in front of each line though @VinayakPingale

Comment: @Nikolay What will you do if the user now wants every line to start with a tab and next day four spaces and next day..

Comment: If your sentence is passed in this way `Precursion.indentByTwoSpaces("The car is blue."+
                    "\nThe sky is blue." +
                    "\nThe house is blue.");`

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on your input.

see this below, this will print out your desired output, given the input does not have spaces after the period. you can adjust accordingly if there is.

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   // notice how my text input doesnt have spaces after the periods
    String text = "The car is blue.The sky is blue.The house is blue.";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String splittedLines[] = text.split("\\.");
    int index = 0;
    while(index != splittedLines.length) {

        // if there are spaces after the periods, consider adjusting this
        sb.append("  ");

        sb.append(splittedLines[index]);
        sb.append("\n");
        index++;
    }

    System.out.print(sb);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you would need to split lines accordingly identifying sentences. However as per the given sample set of lines i would notice the full-stop is there after end of each sentences. Therefore i would suggest to use (.) with regular expression to split lines accordingly. Then you can format your lines accordingly as i shown below.

```
public class AddingSpaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // As shown below, you can have your own sentence even with or without spaces
        String text = "The car is blue.The sky is blue.The house is blue.";

        // Since there are multiple sentences, you can split it from full-stop 
        String splittedLines[] = text.split("\\.");
        for (String line: splittedLines) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("  ").append(line);
            //Print the lines accordingly
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
}
```